# Kotlin how to make 123.456 format

Tags: kotlin, floating-point, decimal-point

I have scales application. I want to display i.e. 123.456g
I have uint8 that represents 123 (scales range is 0 - 150g)
I also have uint16 that represents 456 (scales range .0 - .999g)

My code:

```
val strValue = characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_UINT16,0).toFloat() + ((characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_UINT16,1) or characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_UINT16,2).shl(8)) / 1000f)
```

Produces 51323.457 instead of 123.456
What is wrong?

Comment: val strValue = (characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_UINT16,0)) + ((characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_UINT16,1) or characteristic.getIntValue(FORMAT_UINT16,2).shl(8)) / 1000f)

Comment: @KaroHovhannisyan same result

Answer (score 0):

You're adding floats, not generating a string.

Convert your digits to String, then concatenate them.